# Azure - Manage Billing, User Access & Usage Calculation

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, iaas

I have a business requirement where Azure Subscription owner will Provision User Groups like Infrastructure Admin, Billing Admin, Enterprise Users. Ifra Admin people should login to this Portal & can only see options related to Infra provisioning. Billing Admin people should have access to Azure usage Enterprise wide - And they should be able to generate bills for respective teams(which are part of the organization). Enterprise Users are those who want to procure azure storage, VMs etc. and they want estimate cost for required infra.

I am looking out for a solution/approach for  this requirement. If Azure Portal is already providing this feature then please provide me reference material. If i should build new custom Web application which internally use Azure APIs then let me know about that option as well.

If there are any products which already doing this even am open for that.

Deeply appreciating your help. Thanks a lot :)
Vishal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer by breaking your question in 2 parts:

1. **Managing Users** - This is something you can do today in Azure. Some time ago, Azure announced [`Role-based access control (RBAC)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) and that fits the bill nicely for you as far as managing users and granting them permissions to do things. So in your scenario, the owner will create users and groups in Azure Active Directory and then put these users and groups in appropriate roles. When a user or a group member tries to manage the resources (either by logging into the [portal](http://portal.azure.com) or using other tools like Azure PowerShell Cmdlets), they will only be able to do things the role they are in allows.
2. **Managing Billing** - Though Azure Portal exposes the billing functionality (and there's a billing/usage REST API), it does not have the capability you're looking for. What you would need to do is look for ITFM (IT Financial Management) Systems that has support for Azure. Off the top of my head, two tools come to my mind - Cloudyn & Cloud Cruiser. You can learn more about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/billing-usage-rate-card-overview/. You could always consume the [`Billing/Usage REST API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt218998.aspx) to create a solution of your own. If you're writing your own solution, you may want to check out [`Billing Samples on GitHub`](https://github.com/Azure/BillingCodeSamples).

Comment: Superb! Thank a lot Gaurav that helps. To give you further details on Requirement.- We want our IT infra to be on cloud. To IT Team head will have Org wide Azure subscription & He will create groups for Infra Provisioning & give access rights to his IT teams who can provision VM,DBs, etc. Different team seeking IT Infrastructure can also login to portal and get Indicative Quote. & Later they can request for that Infra to the IT team(who will actually provision it). And later be billed to the respective team. i will surely explore the products you suggested.

Comment: Is there is product comparison matrix available for Cloudyn & Cloud Cruiser

Comment: Fwiw, Cloudyn was acquired by Microsoft in Jul 2017. It's now being offered as Azure Cost Management.